# JSON error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

I am getting the error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

I am only experiencing this problem with Google Trend URL. Other URLs are working fine.

```
function ajaxfun(){

  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://www.google.com/trends/fetchComponent?content=1&hl=en-US&q=fever&cid=TIMESERIES_GRAPH_0&export=3&US&cat=0-45', 
    dataType :"jsonp",
    jsonp: false,
    crossDomain: true,
    error: function(data) {
      console.log('error', data);
    },
    success: function(data) {
      console.log('success', data);
    },
    complete: function() {
      console.log('done');
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: What does `data` contain?

Answer (score 1):

You are not actually receiving a json object. It says,

```
<div id="report">
<div class="timeBandTitle">An error has been detected</div>
<div class="timeBandSubTitle">This page is currently unavailable. Please try again later.<br/> Please make sure your query is valid and try again.<br/> If you're experiencing long delays, consider reducing your comparison items.<br/> Thanks for your patience.</div>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5uqbZ/)
Inspect with developer tools and see it in **Network** tab.

Comment: I have't used trends api but found this link .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7805711/javascript-json-google-trends-api. You might find something useful here.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery by default prevents caching of jsonp by appending `&_={timestamp}` at the end of the url. It causes the error. Add `cache:true` to prevent it.